# What's the difference between setting `compression.type` in Kafka producer vs. defining it in the broker?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to set `compression.type`, and currently setting it in my broker configuration. If I do not define the property in my producer, will it take effect? I do not specify any `compression.type` value or even the property in my producer deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two properties serve different purposes, see [Kafka reference doc](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs).

When defined on a producer side, `compression.type` codec is used to compress every batch for *transmission*, and thus to increase channel throughput.

At the topic (broker) level, `compression.type` defines the codec used to *store* data in Kafka log, i.e. minimize disk usage. Special value `producer` allows Kafka to retain original codec set by producer.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what you wanna compress. You can compress the data sent and you can compress the data stored in topics. So define it on broker side to configure how data is saved or define it on producer side to configure how data is sent

broker side:

> Specify the final compression type for a given topic. This configuration accepts the standard compression codecs ('gzip', 'snappy', 'lz4', 'zstd')

refer to [confluent documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html)

producer side:

> The compression type for all data generated by the producer. The default is none (i.e. no compression). Valid values are none, gzip, snappy, lz4, or zstd.

refer to [confluent documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html)